# Spark dataframe calculate the row-wise minimum

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to put the minimum value of a few columns into a separate column. (Creating the `min` column). The operation is pretty straight forward but I wasn't able to find the right function for that:
A   B   min
1   2   1
2   1   1
3   1   1
1   4   1

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`least`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.least) function, in *pyspark*:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import least
df.withColumn('min', least('A', 'B')).show()
#+---+---+---+
#|  A|  B|min|
#+---+---+---+
#|  1|  2|  1|
#|  2|  1|  1|
#|  3|  1|  1|
#|  1|  4|  1|
#+---+---+---+
```

If you have a list of column names:

```py
cols = ['A', 'B']
df.withColumn('min', least(*cols))
```

Similarly in *Scala*:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.least
df.withColumn("min", least($"A", $"B")).show
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|min|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  1|
|  2|  1|  1|
|  3|  1|  1|
|  1|  4|  1|
+---+---+---+
```

If the columns are stored in a Seq:

```
val cols = Seq("A", "B")    
df.withColumn("min", least(cols.head, cols.tail: _*))
```